# Windows 11 - Hide/Remove virtual desktop indicator while changing

Tags: user-interface, virtual-desktop, windows-11-preview

A few weeks ago, the virtual desktop moving animation returned to Windows 11, including an indicator that shows on what virtual desktop you are.

[image: Icon]

There is any way to disable this indicator?
Tried the registry editor but no lucky.

I think that this thing is a bit annoying.

Comment: Did you try turning Widgets OFF.?

Comment: Yes, the widgets is off

Comment: Older versions of Windows 11 have news and interests as a property of the task bar. Right click on the task bar.  If not these things, then I am not sure.

Comment: Try to use [ViVeTool](https://github.com/thebookisclosed/ViVe) with the following command: `vivetool /disable /id:34508225,40459297`. Before doing that, query the current values using `vivetool /query` and create a System Restore save in order to be able to undo.

Comment: @harrymc Lucien spent all his reputation on the bounty so he could not answer himself but your suggestion worked. Please post it as an answer to receive the bounty!

Comment: @morotspaj: Thanks for the message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To disable the new virtual desktop indicator while changing
desktops do the following:

- Download and unpack
  [ViVeTool](https://github.com/thebookisclosed/ViVe).
  This tool is used to enable or disable Windows features some of
  which may not yet be documented or fully released.
- Run the Command Prompt (CMD) in the unpack directory
- Enter the following command:

  ```
  vivetool /disable /id:34508225,40459297
  ```

  34508225 is the CloudPCSwitch switch and 40459297 is the
  CloudPCFastSwitchDiscovery switch.
  To see a list of all the known switches see the latest
  [FeatureDictionary.pfs](https://github.com/riverar/mach2/blob/master/features/ni_prerelease/amd64/23550.1000.txt).
- A reboot is required to effect the change.

Before doing the above, query the current values using
`vivetool /query` and create a System Restore restore-point
in order to be able to undo the change safely.

Comment: Worked. Thanks.
I had to reboot for it to work